# HTML-CSS: How to text-align starting from the last word?

Tags: html, css

I've got quite challenging design to be done.
Has anyone ever encounter this?

Here is **the design I need**, text is bottom aligned, but the text flowing up if there is not enough space on the line.

```
-------------------


this is 
a pretty long title
-------------------
```

Here **NOT what I need**, easily achieved by `vertical-align: bottom` or `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, but the text flow is not exactly what I desired.

```
-------------------


this is a pretty long
title
-------------------
```

Please notice that the second line has more words than the first line. The wrapping process is *if the text is too long for one line, wrap the first word to line above*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do what you want with straight HTM/CSS without manually setting a breakpoint. Browsers break at the last possible point. How would your design work if the text flowed over 3 or more lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a horrible mess. But it does do what you want. I don't think there's really any good way to get the behavior you're looking for. Good luck!

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var peaches = document.getElementsByClassName("peaches");
    for (var i = 0; i < peaches.length; i++) {
        addSpans(peaches[i]);
        var box = peaches[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        alignSpans(peaches[i].childNodes, box);
    }
}

function addSpans(element) {
    var text = element.innerHTML.split(" ");
    var result = "";
    for (var i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += "<span>" + text[i] + "&nbsp;</span>";
    }
    element.innerHTML = result;
}

function alignSpans(nodes, box) {
    var previousY = null, previousRight = null;

    for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var style = nodes[i].style;
        style.position = "relative";

        var rect = nodes[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (previousY != null && rect.y == previousY) {
            style.right = previousRight;
        } else {
            style.right = rect.x - box.x;
            previousY = rect.y;
            previousRight = style.right;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
p.peaches {
    width: 125px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    direction: rtl;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p class="peaches">
this is a pretty long title
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I will accept this as answers, though I am still expecting more elegant answers. I don't like to touch DOM too much.

Comment: @AlbertSamuel Me neither.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in a fixed `<div>`

```css
div.not_fixed {
    border-top: 1px dashed;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    display: flex;
}

div.fixed {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px dashed;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    display: flex;
}

.fixed span {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="not_fixed">
this is a pretty long title
</div>
<BR>
<div class="fixed">
<span>this is a pretty long title</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this isn't exactly what I want. Please notice that in my example the second line have more words than the first one. I need to make the text wrap reversed